# Algorithms book in JavaScript or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, algorithm

I have seen some books on algorithms such as:

- Introduction to algorithms
- Algorithms Design Manual
- Algorithims in a nutshell
- etc

But most of them are in C/C++ or language i dont know about. I know algorithim is generic topic to grasp but since I dont know C/C++ I find it hard to do so.

Is there any algorithims book with examples written in JavaScript or PHP? I searched on google but found no book.

Comment: Javascript and PHP languages are too poor for effective algorithm explanation.

Comment: @F.Calderan: I know SO is not that but I searched a lot on google as i said in my question. Asked here in hope somebody might have came across such book probably.

Comment: I'm voting to close for the usual reason with such questions. A quick glance at Amazon will turn up 000s of books on algorithms which do not use C/C++ as their pedagogical language.  Why, even TAOCP doesn't and almost any Google for 'Introduction to Algorithms' will find works by Knuth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great book to learn about algorithms:

Introduction to Algorithms, Second Edition, Authors: Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest & Stein

Only a remark, if you want to learn about algorithms, neither javascript or PHP are the best choice

Answer (score 1):

J. M. Muller, Elementary Functions, Algorithms and Implementation. Birkhäuser, Boston, 1997 [Second edition published in 2005]

P. Markstein, IA-64 and Elementary Functions: Speed and Precision. Prentice Hall, 2000 [State of the art algorithms suitable not just for Itanium]

S. L. Moshier, Methods and Programs for Mathematical Functions. E. Horwood, Chichester, England, 1989 [By the author of the Cephes library, www.netlib.org/cephes/]

W. Cody and W. Waite, Software Manual for the Elementary Functions. Prentice Hall, Englewood Cliffs, NJ, 1980

J.F. Hart et al., Computer Approximations. John Wiley and Sons, New York, 1968 [Reprinted with corrections in 1978 by R. E. Krieger Publishing]

L. A. Lyusternik, O. A. Chervonenkis, and A. R. Yanpol'skii, Handbook for Computing Elementary Functions. Pergamon Press, Oxford, 1965.

C. Hastings, Approximations for Digital Computers. Princeton University Press, Princeton, N.J., 1955

Answer (score 0):

C like English in computer languages. You may not need to use it directly in your work. But sometimes you need use it just for communication. It is better to learn some C knowledge. In China, most of students in college will learn C as a basic skill. Maybe not recently. :)